# Does placing breakpoints in VS2010 influence the runtime behavior of the program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

I have investigated this issue now since some time and it seem obvious to me that the placement of ordinary breakpoints influences the runtime behavior of the program dramatically.

I am speaking here of conditional breakpoint e.g. when setting the breakpoint condition to `var == null` then this case never occurs but when I remove the breakpoint the situation that `var == null` occurs often.

Could that be ?

**Appendix:**

Well my code is multi-threaded so it's hard to post code in order to reproduce the error. Basically I have two threads. One is enqueuing items in a queue and the other is permanently dequeing items from the queue. In the code-snipped below I have the situation that the first thread never enqueues null items but for some reason they are finding their way into the queue. That let me insert the if-statement in order to prevent the *NullReferenceException*. Although being a temporary workaround my program did run from then on. Then I was interested in how often a null item gets dequeued from the queue and I placed a conditional breakpoint in the line with the if statement with the condition `inv == null`. The effect now is, when there is a breakpoint inv never seems to be null and when there is no breakpoint inv seems to be often null.

```
public void _dequeue () {

            while (!Signals.TerminateSignal.WaitOne(0, false)) {

                if (Signals.DequeueSignal.WaitOne()) {

                    lock (Queue) {

                        IInvocation inv;
                        Queue.TryDequeue(out inv);

                        // Conditional Breakpoint
                        if (inv != null)
                            inv.Invoke();

                        _poolHooks[PoolIndex].DecrementWaiting();
                        _poolHooks[PoolIndex].IncrementPending();

                        if (Queue.Count == 0) Signals.DequeueSignal.Reset();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Again my problem began when some items in the queue began to be null items although I never add null items. Even for that reason I have placed a line that throws an Exception when there is something null. The Exception never gets thrown but I still have null items in my queue and I have no clue why.

```
public static void EnqueueInvocation (int poolIndex, IInvocation inv ) {

        if (inv == null) throw new Exception("Red Alert");

        lock (_deqThreads[poolIndex].Queue) {

            _poolHooks[poolIndex].IncrementWaiting();


            _deqThreads[poolIndex].Queue.Enqueue(inv);
            _deqThreads[poolIndex].Signals.DequeueSignal.Set();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code.  Let us see if we can reproduce the error.

Comment: @GrayFox374 please refer to my Appendix above.

Comment: Thanks, more info is almost always good.  If you are running the app with no breakpoints, how are you determining the nulls are in the queue? And if that exception never gets throw, even with breakpoints, maybe it's not in the right spot.  Watch shows up in the watch list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"conditional breakpoints" definitely affect timing.  If you have a race condition it will definitely change behavior.  You could also start seeing timeouts.

This is because there is no such thing as a true "conditional breakpoint" on most processors.  What you actually have is "breakpoint, followed conditionally by automatically resuming execution", and that is pretty slow even when the condition isn't satisfied, because the debugger breakpoint handler has to run, read memory, test the condition, and then issue a continue.

---

Now that you've posted your code, I think I see the problem.

You're not checking the return value of `TryDequeue`. When there's nothing to dequeue, inv will be `null`, not because `null` was put into the queue, but because no items are in the queue at all.

Comment: I was wandering why are conditional breakpoints so slow. Your answer seems plausable. Could you provide any sources?

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: [Right here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx) the documentation explains that "A breakpoint condition is **an expression that the debugger evaluates** when a breakpoint is reached."  This makes it clear that the condition is evaluated in software, by a separate process.

Comment: Thank you very much for this neat and detailed answer (and sorry for the delay)

Answer (score 1):

Those breakpoints shouldn't influence your code execution at all (other than slowing down the tagged code lines). Are you sure you didn't accidently write `var = null` or something similar? It might be some timing related issue as well (e.g. your code is slower so some multithreading situation/race condition happens less seldomly), but in the end it's really hard to tell - at least it's no general issue or disadvantage just due to using these.

Comment: No I have definitely written `var == null` and it's heavily influencing the content of the variable `var` (whether it is null or not null). What @BenVoigt is saying in his post above also sounds imaginable for me but the impact that my breakpoint has on my whole execution is pretty high so I am really not sure what effect I am experiencing here ..

Answer (score 1):

No matter where I set a breakpoint, I don't see a difference in behavior in evaluation of x.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new object();
        if (x == null)
        { Console.WriteLine("x is null"); }
        else
        { Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()); }
        x = null;
        if (x == null)
        { Console.WriteLine("x is null"); }
        else
        { Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()); }
    }
```

> System.Object
>   x is null